# Empty documents directory after creating file with NSFileHandle

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, watchkit

I'm writing an application for the Apple watch. I'm using the following method (from [this SE answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057510/creating-a-log-file-in-an-ios-app)) to write to a log file:

```
- (void) writeLogWith: (NSString *) content {

    //Get the file path
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"whathappened.md"];

    //create file if it doesn't exist
    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileName])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:fileName contents:nil attributes:nil];

    //append text to file (you'll probably want to add a newline every write)
    NSFileHandle *file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:fileName];
    [file seekToEndOfFile];
    [file writeData:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [file closeFile];

    return;
}
```

I'm running it by plugging in my phone and running it directly on my watch.  The function is definitely executing (I've stepped thought with the debugger) and it also knows that the file exists and doesn't repeatedly try and create it.

Xcode tells me that the file information is:

```
Printing description of documentsDirectory:
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/8503AD6C-6EC9-4522-A867-27109B01B615/Documents
Printing description of documentsDirectory:
(NSString *) documentsDirectory = 0x16d66890
Printing description of fileName:
(NSString *) fileName = 0x16d66950
Printing description of fileName:
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/8503AD6C-6EC9-4522-A867-27109B01B615/Documents/whathappened.md
```

I'd like to know if it's writing things correctly, but when I look at the container (following [these SE answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121613/browse-the-files-created-on-a-device-by-the-ios-application-im-developing-on-w)), the documents directory is empty. 
[image]

My question is: where did my file go? And how can I find it?

Comment: Have you checked that the file is actually getting written?

Comment: That's kind of what I'm trying to do. When I step though the if statement it responds as if the file exists...

Comment: did my answer help you? Try to copy all my code and use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From other research, the answer appears to be:

If you are storing a file on the Apple Watch, it is stored in it's own container, which isn't visible via xcode.

It indeed, appears to be related to this bug report: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5021353337946112, found via this SE: [How to export shared container of an iOS App with Xcode6.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727337/how-to-export-shared-container-of-an-ios-app-with-xcode6-2)

Answer (score 0):

I think what might be giving you problems is the `NSFileHandle` object. I have written thousands upon thousands of files to the documents folder and I have never used `NSFileHandle` to do this. Simply use the built in method on `NSString` to write your string to the file path.

Try this:

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"whathappened"] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"md"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
}

NSString *string = @"The String You Want To Write.";

NSError *error;
[string writeToFile:filePath atomically:false encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"There was an error writing file\n%@", error.localizedDescription);
}

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    NSLog(@"File exists :)");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"File does not exist :(");
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this made no, difference (although I did try it). The file is being written, and the watch can find it when I go back in, but that's all I have.